# Unordered list of hyperlinks - Match bullet color with link text color

Tags: html, css

I have created a  with all list items as hyperlinks.
What I want here is that the bullet color should match the color of the hyperlink depending on its status(visited or not visited).
I want to use only CSS.
Is this possible?
If I could also match the colors while hovering cursor over the link, it would be great.

Comment: You'd have to add a class to the `li` item and change its colour. Unfortunately, you can't detect the status of link and change the color using only CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
li {
    color:red
}
a {
    color:red;
    display:block
}
li:hover, a:hover{
    color:green
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dnQaM/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the standard bullet :

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

and re-create it in the a

```
a::before {
    content: "\2022";
}
```

now the style of the a includes the bullet

```
a:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

non desired effect: the bullet is underlined as it is now part of the a.

I think that could be overdone with more work, anyway.

[demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/YpJXn/)